# iterating over a Mongo Cursor with finite batch size

Tags: mongodb, cursor, mongodb-query

How can I iterate over the following data cursor? 
Following code gives error  "

> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'forEach'

```
var data = db.profiles.runCommand("aggregate", {
    pipeline: [
        {$limit: 100000},
        {$unwind: "$Items"},
        {   $group: {
                _id: "$Items", count: {$sum: 1}
            },
        },
    ],
    allowDiskUse: true,
    cursor: { batchSize: 100 }
});

data.forEach(printjson) // gives error
```

data variable contains the following content

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5
connecting to: myCollection

    {
        "cursor" : {
            "id" : NumberLong("61248019114"),
            "ns" : "myCollection.profiles",
            "firstBatch" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "alex",
                    "count" : 1
                },
                {
                    "_id" : "james",
                    "count" : 1
                } .......
            },
        "ok" : 1
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT :**

From MongoDB [RunCommand Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#dbcmd.aggregate):

> Using the aggregate command to return a cursor is a low-level operation, intended for authors of drivers. Most users should use the db.collection.aggregate() helper provided in the mongo shell or in their driver. In 2.6 and later, the aggregate() helper always returns a cursor.

You need to send [OP_GET_MORE](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/#wire-op-get-more) message to iterate over the cursor.

Instead use the [aggregate() helper](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate).

```
var data= db.profiles.aggregate([
    {$limit: 100000},
        {$unwind: "$Items"},
        {   $group: {
                _id: "$Items", count: {$sum: 1}
            },
        },
    ],
    {
        allowDiskUse: true,
        cursor: { batchSize: 100}
    }
)
```

This returns you a cursor. You can use `forEach` method for iterating it.

```
data.forEach(printjson)
```

Comment: my aim is to iterate over a huge result set. if you notice, I used cursor: { batchSize: 100 } so that I can iterate over the result set in batches. The result I get in "data" after running the aggregate command contains only 100 results. What is the way out to get complete result set in a iterative manner without crossing doc size limit? @thegreenogre

Comment: @comiventor Which MongoDB driver are you using? What version of mongod/mongos are you using? Also can you check the type of `data` to make sure you are getting a cursor back?

Comment: db version v2.6.5. I have added details of data variable in the question

Comment: @comiventor Edited the answer. I am not sure how to use the cursor with db.runCommand. I checked the MongoDB and Drivers Manual but couldn't find a way. If you are interested you can check the implementation of `runcommand cursor` in [pymongo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/command_cursor.py).